# QtDesktop components crash on mouse move

Tags: windows-8, qt5

I'm trying to use Qt 5 with QtDesktop components in Windows 8 x64 and when I build and run app and move mouse, app is crashing with this message in log:

```
QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
```

It happens only if mouse move in any component, if i have qml like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtDesktop 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Button {
        text: "testButton"
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

everything will be ok before I move cursor into button. Somebody have any ideas what is it and how i can fix this? It isn't the error in my code because building tests/tableviewmodels and examples/ApplicationTemplate gives the same result

If it important, I use Visual Studio 2010 Express + Qt Creator 2.6.1

PS not sure, but I think I build and run QtDesktopComponents on this PC about two weeks ago and there wasn't this error, and it was windows update after that

**UPD**

It was Qt Quick Components bug, fixed in https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCOMPONENTS-1287

Comment: Not specific to Windows 8. I have already seen the same error on Windows 7. Perhaps it would be useful to report the bug to the Qt Project ?

Comment: I had posted this to QtProject forum (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23906/) Friday and don't have answers yet, but if you get the same error it's look like bug. I will report the bug and give link here

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCOMPONENTS-1287